# How to activate/connect Mysql database to my wampserver?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I've been struggling for days now and I have no idea on how to proceed, I feel helpless, and I still don't understand what is the error.

So! I created a few virtual hosts with wampserver, let's call one of them "Namesite", it is the one I'm working on. Namesite is growing well, I admit I had many errors, but I think it is because of the old code of my files I'm dealing with, which is fine. Namesite is pretty useless without a database though, especially if I want to test every inch of it, so in order to login I must use an account. And I can create it from the database, not elsewhere. So i created a new SQL database on MyphpAdmin, specifically for Namesite, I then created the new account to login, changed the file inside Namesite that allows it to connect to the database, and I hit refresh for the new changes. Fact is, it doesn't work. Namesite is not connected to the database in anyway, and I tried everything to connect to it.

The code Namesite asks to complete to connect to the database is this:

```
$PARAMETERS['database']['username'] = 'username';
$PARAMETERS['database']['password'] = 'password';
$PARAMETERS['database']['database_name'] = 'database';
$PARAMETERS['database']['url'] = 'localhost';
```

Since I connect to MyphpAdmin by the defoult "root" I used it as a username, no password, name of the database, that I will call it "groot" and left localhost. Didn't work. So inside of MyphpAdmin I created a specific account user for "groot" database, named "loli", and it became "Loli" "password" "groot" "localhost". Still nothing. Then I read online that I should add the port after localhost, and it became:

```
$PARAMETERS['database']['username'] = 'Loli';
$PARAMETERS['database']['password'] = 'password';
$PARAMETERS['database']['database_name'] = 'groot';
$PARAMETERS['database']['url'] = 'localhost:3305';
```

It still doesn't work! what am I doing wrong? what is the problem? Everything must be in localhost since I'm working on it in a virtual host, so how can I connect a database to my server? Thank you!

Edit: Ok so, it appears that it works for some servers, but not everyone, so I'm a bit confused because I don't understand why although I typed the same entries for everyone except for the name of the database.

Comment: default port is 3306

Comment: I changed it though, it's connected to the 3305. Should I try to change it back?

Comment: if you changed default port you should change back. also if you created user in lowercase you should change it to lowercase

Comment: Ok, I changed it back to its default now, and it is in lowercase, still stuck..